# springMVC3.0 response body encoding issue

Tags: spring-mvc

the default charset of @ResponseBody is iso-8859-1,
how to change to utf8?

configuration below does't seem to work.

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name = "messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name = "supportedMediaTypes">
                        <list>
                        <value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: "i use springmvc alone(without spring)" - no, you don't.

Comment: check the discussion here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81858-ResponseBody-and-UTF-8 in particular the post of springbee

Comment: thank for the link. "without spring" i mean i don't config spring in web.xml, just the DispatcherServlet

Answer (score 3):

You can add produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" to request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/create/document", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public void create(Document document, HttpServletRespone respone) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    
    Document newDocument = DocumentService.create(Document);
    
    return jsonSerializer.serialize(newDocument);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tomcat you also need to specifying `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` on `<Connector>` in the Tomcat server.xml config, as described here:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8